# Limit number of ForeignKey elements in list view

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I have a resources like these:

models.py

```
class Place(models.Model):
        id           = models.CharField(max_length = 256, primary_key = True)
        name         = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)
class Review(models.Model):
        id           = models.CharField(max_length = 256, primary_key = True)
        p_id         = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name = 'place_review')
        text         = models.TextField()
```

api.py

```
class ReviewResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Review.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'place_review'

class PlaceResource(ModelResource):
    place_review = fields.OneToManyField(ReviewResource, 
                                'place_review', 
                                full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Place.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'place'
```

Using above model and resource, I want to limit number of reviews in list view of Place to 3, in detail/show view I want to show more reviews (possible different style, e.g. if review contains image, show it in detail view, hide it in list view)

I have tried to put `attribute=lambda bundle: Review.objects.all()[:3],` but whenever I don't have any reviews for place it fails with `The model '' has an empty attribute ' at 0x7f0a180d0de8>' and doesn't allow a null value.` message.

What can you suggest for this case, are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Encountered same problem :)